# JPanel nested in JScrollPane exceeds its size when adding multiple components

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a layout for my app and have a problem with JSCrollPane, specifically with size mismatch of the pane. I need to create a scrolled view that would automatically create a scroll bar and fit its size to the scroll pane, however right now I can't. What I want to achieve is to have scrollbar as well as pane size not exceeding fixed values (app for specific device).

[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9lY0.png)

[Desired view (poor paint skills), scrollbar doesnt exceed panel size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCIFW.png)

```
class FrameworkPrototype extends JFrame{


private static FrameworkPrototype instance = null;
private int _windowWidth = 800, _windowHeigth = 480;
private ButtonPanel _btnPanel = new ButtonPanel(); 
private HeaderPanel _hdrPanel = new HeaderPanel(); //extends JPanel
private ContentPanel _cntPanel = new ContentPanel(); //extends JPanel

public static FrameworkPrototype getInstance(){
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new FrameworkPrototype();
    return instance;
}

private void initializeGUI(){
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(_windowWidth, _windowHeigth);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initializeContentPanel();
    initializeButtonPanel();
    initializeHeaderPanel();
    addComponents();
}

private void initializeHeaderPanel(){
    _hdrPanel.setSize(new Dimension(800, 50));
    _hdrPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
    _hdrPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
}

private void initializeButtonPanel(){
    _btnPanel.setSize(new Dimension(200, 600));
    _btnPanel.setLocation(0, 50);
    _btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
}

private void initializeContentPanel(){
    _cntPanel.setSize(new Dimension(600, 410));
    _cntPanel.setLocation(200,50);
    _cntPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());    
}

private void addComponents(){   
    add(_hdrPanel);
    add(_btnPanel);
    add(_cntPanel);
}

private FrameworkPrototype(){
    super("Prototype");
    initializeGUI();
}
```

Here is the problematic part

```
final class ButtonPanel extends JScrollPane {
private JTextArea _tempTextArea = new JTextArea();
private JPanel _btnPanel = new JPanel();

public ButtonPanel(){
    setVisible(true);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    initializeButtonPanel();
    setViewportView(_btnPanel);
    revalidate();

}

private void initializeButtonPanel(){
    _btnPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,600));
    _btnPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(_btnPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    _tempTextArea.setText("Choose proper function");
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));       _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 1"));
    _btnPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));
}
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't need to (and I'd discourage from) extending from `JScrollPane`, instead, have a look at the [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface, which will allow you to define the `PreferredScrollableViewportSize`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've managed to implement two solutions: one containing your tip and the other to change absolute layout to border one.